# php undefined index id but if(isset($_POST['id'])) statement working fine

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to php and have been reading on every forum about this issue but nothing works it still gives me the warning: undefined index. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST['redeem_points'])){

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $points = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['points']);
            $sql = "UPDATE users set user_points = user_points - '".$points."' WHERE user_id = '". $id ."' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if ($result === TRUE) {
            echo '<script> window.alert("Points Redeemed successfully !")
                        location.href = "admin_manage_points.php" </script>';
                }
                else{
                    echo "failed";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Either initialise variables and indexes, or if you cannot (ie they come from a form) then check if they are set with `isset()` or `empty()`. You answered your own question in your post title

Answer (score 1):

use `isset()` on `$_POST` array elements, to make sure they are set, e.g.:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
```

If you use PHP 7 or higher you can use the following:

```
// returns the value of $_POST['id']
// or returns false if it does not exist.
$id = $_POST['id'] ?? false;
```

The null coalescing operator (??) returns the first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your reply I tried it but its giving me a parse error, I'm using php 5.5

Comment: i meant `$id = $_POST['id'] ?? false;` is PHP 7 shorthand for `$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : false` @yangpiper

Answer (score 0):

You check an other index than you use.

```
isset($_POST['redeem_points']) // this will be checked
$id = $_POST['id']; // that is was you are using
```

Comment: thank you for your reply could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: I messed around a bit and tried to add points for a specific user and it worked  $sql = "UPDATE users set user_points = user_points - '".$points."' WHERE user_id = '2';

Comment: I mean he checked only the index `redeem_points`, but this isnt used in the code. But the index `id` is used in the code and will not be checked. It seems to me a little bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
```

And i was wondering, where does "undefined index error" come from? php or javascript?
Because your javascript code has error too. It should like this;

```
echo '<script> window.alert("Points Redeemed successfully !");
                        location.href = "admin_manage_points.php" </script>';
```

Comment: the error "undefined index" comes from the "$id =$_POST['id'];" line, thanks for pointing out the error in javascript.

Comment: ok, maybe you must check id in first if condition. I thought, integer cast not good idea, it masks the error.

Comment: Casting to int is not the way to handle a potential undefined index. Also, it'll set it to `(int) 0` if a string is passed (just FYI)